# I want to add more css property to my html element using Jquery means I dont want to remove the previous one just simply add more to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- jquery-3.4.1.min -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="epic" style="color:red">hello this is title</div>
<div>hello this is title</div>
<input type="button" placeholder="click it" value="click">
</body>
</html>
```

custom.js

```
$( document ).ready(function($){       
   $(":button").click(function(){    
    $(".epic").attr("style","font-size:100px");    
   });        
});
```

Now What I want Is when I click the button than I should be able to give the font-size that I want but keep the previous color red also .
The code that I have written makes the font 100 but color is gone ,so Is there any way to keep the color and still be able to modify the font.

Comment: Set `.css` instead of `.style`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`.css()`**](https://api.jquery.com/css/) to set the particular style property (*font-size*):

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $(":button").click(function(){
    $(".epic").css("font-size", "100px");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="epic" style="color:red">hello this is title</div>
<div>hello this is title</div>
<input type="button" placeholder="click it" value="click">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.css` method instead. And pass a object of CSS properties. When you will call it again, it will just add the new properties to existing one.

**In your solution, you are overwriting the complete `style` attribute everytime. So it is removing the older properties.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(":button").click(function() {
    $(".epic").css({
      "font-size": "50px",
      "background-color": "blue"
    });
    $(".epic").css({
      "color":"white"
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="epic" style="color:red">title</div>
<div>hello this is title</div>
<input type="button" placeholder="click it" value="click">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery `addClass()` method to keep the original CSS class and add a new one:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".epic").addClass("clicked");
});
```

And in the CSS:

```
.clicked {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```